# PHP MySQLI - Table Count ends with zero

Tags: php, mysqli

I hope some one can help me with this strange problem.

My problem is when I count the records in my table it returns zero.

When I use the same SQLI Query in phpMyAdmin I get the right number.

I can also get a read out on all records, so i know that connection is okay.
Now I've try out many things, like comment out `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, change between digit and string and also without the "while" loop as there are only one value to return, but with no luck so far.

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this code?

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM gps";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare ($mysqli, $prep_stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 'i');
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $gps_pos);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $format = "Antal GPS Positioner: %d \n";
    printf($format, $gps_pos);
}
```

Comment: You didn't use a placeholder so there's nothing bound. You should have gotten an error about that. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php and try removing the space in `COUNT (*)` => `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Plus, you're trying to bind a single integer to all columns, probably (another reason) why it's failing.

Comment: Try doing your query like this:
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT COUNT (*) as counted FROM gps";
Then get counted.

Comment: @ Fred
I really don't think the bind_param is needed.
Got inspiration from Mysql.com.
And there: create query -> execute -> bind_result-> fetch. :-)

Comment: @vr_driver
No change if query is as you suggest. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the binding for a minute and try doing your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT (*) as counted FROM gps";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows ($result); 

if ($num > 0 )
{ 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
    $Counted = $row['Counted'];
    $format = "Antal GPS Positioner: %d \n";
    printf($format, $Counted)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but no luck with that either and no Error Message. Have also tried with one example from did find on another site.
My best solution so far, is to do a ordinary query "SELECT * From table" and use a counter for each row that's fetch and just throw away the data as is not needed. :-)

Comment: change "$Counted = $row['Counted'];" to "$Counted = $row['counted'];" It should have a been a lower case. If you can't figure this all out, there's something wrong. You've got to have you database connection there too under the $dbc.

Comment: I did see the Upper/lower case mispell. I know that the connection is okay, as i'll use it, when i'll do a read out from the database.
If it did't work, i could't use the counter. :-)

Comment: Does that select statement work in your mysql browser? Eg, phpmyadmin or mysql workbench?